# Oracle 9i SQL query - join multiple time the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I've a strange behavior with a simple SQL query. I work on Oracle 9i. 
I just wanna be sure there is no stupid error in my query. If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong. Here's the query :

```
select p.PARTNUM,
        p.N_DATAA, dataa1.ID_DATA as ID_DATAA,
        p.N_DATAF, dataf1.ID_DATA as ID_DATAF,
        p.N_DATAS, datas1.ID_DATA as ID_DATAS
from PIECES p
left join DATA dataa1 on
              dataa1.N_DATA = p.N_DATAA AND
              dataa1.REV_DATA = ( select max(dataa2.REV_DATA) from DATA dataa2 
                                  where dataa2.N_DATA = p.N_DATAA )
left join DATA dataf1 on
              dataf1.N_DATA = p.N_DATAF AND
              dataf1.REV_DATA = ( select max(dataf2.REV_DATA) from DATA dataf2 
                                  where dataf2.N_DATA = p.N_DATAF )
left join DATA datas1 on
              datas1.N_DATA = p.N_DATAS AND
              datas1.REV_DATA = ( select max(datas2.REV_DATA) from DATA datas2 
                                  where datas2.N_DATA = p.N_DATAS )
where p.PARTNUM='MYPARTNUM';
```

and here is the result :

```
"PARTNUM"      "N_DATAA"  "ID_DATAA"  "N_DATAF"   "ID_DATAF"  "N_DATAS"   "ID_DATAS"                     
"MYPARTNUM"    "A23240"   "300"       "F4130"     "398"       "S2330"     ""
```

My problem appears on the field ID_DATAS (an ID_DATAS should be returned, I'm sure, see below), it acts as if it ignores the last join and retrieve no data. If I delete the SECOND join, it works perfectly. It seems like if Oracle does not support more than 2 left join... (???)

Here an other example when I switch the two last left join (in this case the problem appears on ID_DATAF) :

```
select p.PARTNUM,
        p.N_DATAA, dataa1.ID_DATA as ID_DATAA,
        p.N_DATAF, dataf1.ID_DATA as ID_DATAF,
        p.N_DATAS, datas1.ID_DATA as ID_DATAS
from PIECES p
left join DATA dataa1 on
              dataa1.N_DATA = p.N_DATAA AND
              dataa1.REV_DATA = ( select max(dataa2.REV_DATA) from DATA dataa2 
                                  where dataa2.N_DATA = p.N_DATAA )
left join DATA datas1 on
              datas1.N_DATA = p.N_DATAS AND
              datas1.REV_DATA = ( select max(datas2.REV_DATA) from DATA datas2 
                                  where datas2.N_DATA = p.N_DATAS )
left join DATA dataf1 on
              dataf1.N_DATA = p.N_DATAF AND
              dataf1.REV_DATA = ( select max(dataf2.REV_DATA) from DATA dataf2 
                                  where dataf2.N_DATA = p.N_DATAF )
where p.PARTNUM='MYPARTNUM';
```

and here is the result :

```
"PARTNUM"      "N_DATAA"  "ID_DATAA"  "N_DATAF"   "ID_DATAF"  "N_DATAS"   "ID_DATAS"                     
"MYPARTNUM"    "A23240"   "300"       "F4130"     ""          "S2330"     "400"
```

Thank you for your help :)

EDIT : add fully qualified column names in queries (does not solve my problem)

Comment: You should always use fully qualified column names as soon as you have more than one table - especially if those columns exist in more than one table. In that case your query is going to fail badly if you upgrade to a current (=supported) version of Oracle at some point.

Comment: Thank you a_horse_with_no_name^^, you're totally right, but the columns on which I don't use a fully qualified column name do exist in only one table. I've tried by giving fully qualified column name for each columns mentioned and it does not solve my problem :(

Comment: Question edited to use fully qualified column names in queries as advised by a_horse_with_no_name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably experiencing a bug with your old version of Oracle. Oracle 9i was the first version to support ANSI join and came with a few bugs with ANSI-join syntax.

Your query won't run in an up-to-date (11.2) Oracle db ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e86aa/1)), you will run into:

```
ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery
```

So the bug in your Oracle version is that this query shouldn't return *any* result. In any case make sure that you're running the latest patch set. Also it may be a good idea to plan an upgrade, this version *is* deprecated -- extended support ended **3 years** ago!

You'll have to rewrite your query, for instance like this:

```
SQL> WITH filtered_data AS (
  2     SELECT n_data, rev_data, id_data
  3       FROM DATA d
  4      WHERE rev_data = (SELECT MAX(rev_data)
  5                          FROM DATA d_in
  6                         WHERE d_in.n_data = d.n_data)
  7  )
  8  SELECT p.partnum,
  9         p.n_dataa,
 10         A.id_data AS id_dataa,
 11         p.n_dataf,
 12         F.id_data AS id_dataf,
 13         p.n_datas,
 14         S.id_data AS id_datas
 15    FROM pieces p
 16    LEFT JOIN filtered_data A ON A.n_data = p.n_dataa
 17    LEFT JOIN filtered_data S ON S.n_data = p.n_datas
 18    LEFT JOIN filtered_data F ON F.n_data = p.n_dataf
 19   WHERE p.PARTNUM = 'MYPARTNUM';

PARTNUM       N_DATAA  ID_DATAA  N_DATAF  ID_DATAF  N_DATAS  ID_DATAS
------------- -------- --------- -------- --------- -------- ---------
MYPARTNUM     A23240   300       F4130    398       S2330    400
```